# Trying to sum a groupBy value in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, sum

I have this code suggested to me. I am trying to sum the stock_in_qty and stock_out_qty.

```
$warehouse1stocks = Warehouse1stocks::select(
                        "order_item_id",
                        Warehouse1stocks::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty'),
                        Warehouse1stocks::raw('SUM(stock_out_qty) as stock_out_qty'))->groupBy('order_item_id')->get();
// dd($warehouse1stocks);
return view("warehouse1.index", compact("warehouse1stocks", $warehouse1stocks));
```

My problem is this error

[image]

I tried to look for an answer from other questions here and I think my code seems ok but why am i still having that error?

what do you think is the problem with my code? thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the table structure and some sample data i will write it in `ORM` way

Comment: Hi @Manojkiran.I just realize that the real question should be how will I be able to groupBy the data using unique id which is the "order_item_id". if you would like to answer please follow this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146063/how-to-group-the-value-of-unique-id-in-laravel-5-5 thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```php
Warehouse1stocks::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty')
```

write:

```php
DB::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty')
```

when defining the write expressions

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
$warehouse1stocks = Warehouse1stocks::select(
                        "order_item_id",
                        \DB::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty'),
                        \DB::raw('SUM(stock_out_qty) as stock_out_qty'))->groupBy('order_item_id')->get();
// dd($warehouse1stocks);
return view("warehouse1.index", compact("warehouse1stocks", $warehouse1stocks));
```